# logging all activities from ninject3

Tags: asp.net, ninject

Is it possible to log all activities which ninject doing when trying to resolve every dependency? I got an exception "Instances of abstract classes cannot be created." and I can't find where the problem is. In the stack trace there is no info on which dependency this exception was thrown. In VS I have enabled debugging for this app, but I can't intercept this exception. No exception is caught by VS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try ninject.extensions.logging and use log4net or nlog
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.logging and
http://www.ninject.org/extensions.html